# Remove line numbers of plugin editor.md

Tags: javascript, markdown, editor.md

I  am using  [editor.md](https://github.com/pandao/editor.md),
the editor display line numbers as default,

[image]

I want to hide the line number and find it setting `lineNumber` as false,

```
$(function(){
      editormd.markdownToHTML("editormd-view", {
      htmlDecode      : "style,script,iframe",  // you can filter tags decode
      lineNumbers     : false,
    });
});
```

However, it did not take effect,

I traverse through the source code `editormd.js` all day long to comment out keywords "linenums" , "linen" etc, but still not solve the problem.

The source file is markdown without line numbers.

Does anyone encounter such a problem with this editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
.CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper {display: none;}
```

Or set that style for each element with that class in javascript.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper")[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: @TDR try doing with javascript, and put the javascript in a `window.onload`